# Disable compiling including lint or linter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, linter

Im having issues building my website (built from vue-cli scaffolding) which is meant to also be homework for students.

Linter rules such as tabulation and extra spaces are causing the app to display them as a fatal error.

Code and syntax violations sure why not but spaces and tabs?

This will be impossible for the students.

How can I decide what linter rules get included in the webpack/babel compilation and which ones are ignored?

Comment: Just remove [this block of code](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L34-L45) to get rid of the linter. IMO linting has no real place when using HMR.

Comment: I disagree, especially for students. They should be taught good coding standards whilst they're learning. I agree, sometimes they may be too strict but you can define the linting rules in your `.eslintrc.js`.

Comment: Worth noting as well, you can set the severity level of errors so that they show as warnings instead of stopping the app compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [eslint config page](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring). You'll be able to configure the rules using `.eslintrc.js`. You can also define paths that won't be linted using a `.eslintignore` file.

As an example, this is the one I'm using in my current project:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  env: {
    browser: true
  },
  // https://github.com/feross/standard/blob/master/RULES.md#javascript-standard-style
  extends: [
    'standard'
  ],
  // required to lint *.vue files
  plugins: [
    'html',
    'import'
  ],
  globals: {
    'cordova': true,
    'DEV': true,
    'PROD': true,
    '__THEME': true
  },
  // add your custom rules here
  'rules': {
    // allow paren-less arrow functions
    'arrow-parens': 0,
    'one-var': 0,
    'import/first': 0,
    'import/named': 2,
    'import/namespace': 2,
    'import/default': 2,
    'import/export': 2,
    // allow debugger during development
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0,
    'brace-style': [2, '1tbs', { 'allowSingleLine': true }],
    'no-return-assign': 0
  }
}
```

And my ignore file:

```
build/*.js
config/*.js
dist/*.js
```

Comment: That didn't do it for me. I still get a crash if there's one extra tab. I copy pasted your files.

Comment: Try adding: `"indent": ["warn", 2]` to the rules. Basically, we need to tell eslint to warn, not error. This is the related page: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent

Comment: amazing! thanks. I also l found a way to disable extra white spaces check : `"skipBlankLines": 0 "ignoreComments": 0`